# What are the StepState of an Angular Material Stepper Component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to customize the `step-numbers` like `1`,`2`,`3` shown for each step with a different icon in the `initial state` of the stepper

I am able to currently replace the `step-numbers` with by using a `matStepperIcon` value of `edit` state in the `ng-template` as below

With this, I see that only when we move to next step the previous-steps `step-number` is changed to `icon` (`donut_large`).

```
  <mat-vertical-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
        <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit"><mat-icon>donut_large</mat-icon> </ng-template>
    <mat-step >
```

...code excluded for brevity
            ...

1) do i need to use the `donut_large` icon with some other `matStepperIcon` value other than edit . so see that the donut_large icon is shown on the steps in the Steppers `reset` state as well. 
2) What all other `StepState`, values can be used , since when I am trying to use any other values like `done` or `reset` for `matStepperIcon`it doesn't work. It only works when i use the value as `edit` . As per documentation on angular-material website `matStepperIcon` refers to

`@Input('matStepperIcon')     |
name: StepState                 |    Name of the icon to be overridden.`

Comment: Are you able to put a https://stackblitz.com example together?

Answer (score 4):

Here is what StepState in Angular Material (more precisely in CDK) is (from the [source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/stepper/stepper.ts)):

```
/** The state of each step. */
export type StepState = 'number' | 'edit' | 'done' | 'error' | string;

/** Enum to represent the different states of the steps. */
export const STEP_STATE = {
  NUMBER: 'number',
  EDIT: 'edit',
  DONE: 'done',
  ERROR: 'error'
};
```

Here is an example code:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper>

  <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
    <mat-icon>fingerprint</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="done">
    <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="number">
    <mat-icon>code</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="error">
    <mat-icon>highlight_off</mat-icon>
  </ng-template>

  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 1 label</ng-template>
    <p>Step 1</p>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 2 label</ng-template>
    <p>Step 2</p>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 3 label</ng-template>
    Step 3
  </mat-step>

</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

You can also create your own steps, check out the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#overriding-icons) or the [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nvpeejxkkavr?file=app%2Fstepper-states-example.ts) at StackBlitz.